# Calculating Time (additive amounts)

Tags: qgis

In QGIS 3.6.1 Noosa I have a column in the attribute table (`Install Date`) formatted as `DATE` that I want to add 100 or 60 years (`Replacement Date`) to, also in `DATE` format, for use in Time Manager.

I have tried creating a new field in the Field Calculator but get NULL values out. Expression used was `todate("Install_Da"+'100 Years")`.

I can get a result using Integer formats using `left(Install_Da,4)` then another column adding 100 years but then it doesn't run in Time Manager due to wrong format.

What is the proper way to add years to a date?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the 60 or 100 years to an interval:

```
"Install_Da" + to_interval('60 years')
```